# "one version rule" in Java dependency management--is this a good idea

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

For security reason, we update third-party dependencies frequently.
We use maven as our  dependency management tool , but it's still a hard work since we have 100+ projects to update.

1、How can we do this fast and sound?

Sometimes we have to change our code to use the new dependency. Sometimes we don't have enough time to test and cause exceptions in product environment, like NoSuchMethodError.

2、Is [One version rule](https://opensource.google/docs/thirdparty/oneversion/) a good idea in java? Have someone done this before?

for example, our Project A depends spring-webmvc 5.3.9 and Project B depends on spring-webmvc 5.2.0. We want both A and B to depend on spring-webmvc 5.3.9. In fact, we want our all projects to depend on the same version.

Thank you

Comment: "cause exceptions in product environment, like NoSuchMethodError" - oh darn... there are so many things that are wrong within this single phrase of yours.

Comment: but you need a common bom project if you want to have same dependency everywhere

Comment: Please excuse me for my poor English...  Yes we are trying to do this:  define a common parent pom

Comment: this is not about your English, no. I meant to say that this is a serious negligence to have this kind of errors in production. Unit tests should catch that, far, far sooner.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes we have to change our code to use the new dependency.
> Sometimes we don't have enough time to test and cause exceptions in
> product environment, like NoSuchMethodError.

This sentence sounds like you have bad practices inside your organisation. You should put in place a solid policy on your testing and deployment (`CI/CD`) process.

A good practice is to implement a `BOM` or a `parent POM project` that will manage all your common dependencies. It is very good when it comes to manage and centralize your librairies versions.

1. Before any changes goes to the production server, it should be tested
2. You have to define a process for your tests : `unit test` > `integration tests` > `end-to-end` test
3. Every new implementation should pass `pull/request` and review process
4. Try to implement AGILE workflow in your team

My answer is not a silver bullet approach but I hope it will help you quite a lot. It is clearly an organisation issue that you have in your team or your enterprise. You have to implement [Software Development Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process).